# transition rate diagram for M/M/1 queue

Tags: transition

I do not know how to   create the following diagram by using tikz.
[image]

How do I create this?

Answer (score 4):

You can draw arrows with the command

```
\draw[->] (0,0)--(1,0);
```

You can add the greek letters with nodes

```
\node[below] at (0,0) {\lambda};
```

You can draw the dots with

```
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (2pt);
```

With these elements you can create your diagramm.

Comment: +1 for providing just the key pieces when there is no MWE